# How to re-open Bootstrap modal accidentally closed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, window, restore

I have a few different modals on a page, and it all works as it should, but if a user makes some input on form fields in a modal and then accidentally clicks outside of the modal (which closes it), they loose their changes, since if the user clicks the same button they pressed to open the modal, the data they entered will be overwritten with data pulled from the database.

So I'd like to have a function for "reopen last closed modal" that simply shows the modal again in it's last used state - with whatever data was in it.

Essentially like a Ctrl-Z for accidentally closing a modal.

It's really simple if you know the ID of the modal. Such as:

```
$('#myModal1').modal('show'); });
```

But because I have several different modals available on a page, and I don't want to have a bunch of "restore" buttons, I need to be able to detect the ID of the last closed modal.

If there's not a simpler way, I could capture the ID each time a modal is closed, and then use that ID if the modal needs to be reopened without changing its data. Something like this:

```
$('#myModal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var LastModal = '#myModal1';
})

$('#myModal2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var LastModal = '#myModal2';
})

function reOpen() {
$(LastModal).modal('show');
}
```

But I'm guessing there's a way that's simpler and doesn't require me to state all my modals ID's in JS/jQuery. Any ideas?

Comment: You could add a common CSS class to every modal on the page, then have just one general event listener to capture ID, e.g. `$('.modal-class').on(hidden.bs.modal', (e) => var LastModal = $(e.target).attr('id'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a few tweaks, and this is working well for me now, with essentially no other hassle than a few short lines of code in my script file.

```
var LastModal;
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', (e) => {LastModal = $(e.target).attr('id'); })
function reOpen() { $('#'+LastModal).modal('show');}
```

Just use the style class "modal" for your modals, and to call the "reOpen", just have something like:

```
<span onclick='reOpen();'>Reopen</span>
```

*Thanks @marekful for your suggestion!*

**Also**, if you want to access this (or any other function) by pressing **Ctrl+Z**, you can add this:

```
// press Ctrl+Z to restore modal
$(document).keydown(function(evt){
    if (evt.keyCode==90 && (evt.ctrlKey)){
        evt.preventDefault();
        reOpen();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have my modal classes set as modal fade (the standard) but get an undefined variable when they close, did you ever have this issue?